# Removing /N character from a column in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, newline, data-cleaning

I have a column with the headlines of articles. The **headlines** are like this(in Greek):
[\n, [Μητσοτάκης: Έχει μεγάλη σημασία οι φωτισ..

How can I remove this character: **[\n, ?**

I have tried this but nothing happened:

```
 df['Title'].replace('\n', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Please clarify whether you're looking to remove the character `\n` from every entry, or if you want to replace any entries that are solely `\n` to be blank? It would help if you included example input and expected output

Comment: I want to remove every character \n from every entry.

Answer (score 2):

.replace() does not change the dataframe by default, it returns a new dataframe.  Use the inplace pararameter.

```
>>> import pandas
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame([{"x": "a\n"}, {"x": "b\n"}, {"x": "c\n"}])
>>> df['x'].replace('\n', '', regex=True)  # does not change df
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: x, dtype: object
>>> df  # df is unchanged
     x
0  a\n
1  b\n
2  c\n
>>> df['x'].replace('\n', '', regex=True, inplace=True)
>>> df  # df is changed
   x
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

Comment: It looks like OP wants to replace a part of text with other text. They are looking for the vectorized string replace which runs the replace on each element of the column, not `df.replace()` which replaces entire elements

Comment: I'm sorry, but you misunderstand their problem.  The only problem is that they did not use inplace.  Their approach works fine if they do.

Comment: I believe my response still does what they want, but until they provide some examples we can only guess.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The `regex=True` makes it use `re.sub()` under the hood which replaces substrings. Sorry about that! Have a +1 :)

Comment: No worries at all.  Core Python is pretty logical but often the 3rd party libraries are black magic.  Pandas, nympy, matplotlib, sklearn.  I find for these libraries I just kind of have to memorize more than understand.  I did not even know about this feature of the regex parameter until I saw this question and tested it for myself.  The inplace issue though, I recognized at once.  A very common Pandas trap.

Comment: I hadn't worked with the `regex` either! That's why I suggested the vectorized element-wise function given by `df.str.replace()` (which cannot do an inplace replacement, so needs reassignment)

Comment: I tried this:  df['Title'] = df['Title'].replace('\n', '', regex=True, inplace=True) but all the headlines are converted to None

Comment: You’re mixing solutions, you have to do one or the other.  If you use the inplace parameter, do not reassign the data frame.

Comment: I'd just like to add that the vectorized `df.str.replace()` is noticeably faster (at least 4x for all my attempts) than the regular `df.replace()` with regex.

Comment: Regex pattern matching is unsurprisingly more computationally intensive than a straight up string operation.  My intuitive approach would have been a dataframe .apply() operation with a lambda function using replace (less memorizing of library-specific operations).  But to me, that wasn't the question.  The question was "What am I doing wrong?" not "What is the computationally ideal solution to this problem?"  What they were doing wrong was not using the inplace parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for

```
df['Title'].str.replace('\n', '')
```

Also remember that this replacement doesn't happen in-place. To change the original dataframe, you're going to have to do

```
df['Title'] = df['Title'].str.replace('\n', '')
```

[`df.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) provides vectorized string functions to operate on each value in the column. `df.str.replace('\n', '')` runs the `str.replace()` function on each element of `df`.

[`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) replaces *entire values* in the column with the given replacement.

For example,

```
data = [{"x": "hello\n"}, {"x": "yello\n"}, {"x": "jello\n"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# df: 
#          x
# 0  hello\n
# 1  yello\n
# 2  jello\n

df["x"].str.replace('\n', '')

# df["x"]:
# 0    hello
# 1    yello
# 2    jello

df["x"].replace('yello\n', 'bello\n')

# df["x"]: 
# 0    hello\n
# 1    bello\n
# 2    jello\n
```