# removing new lines from a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean my dataset I scrapped the data from abjjad. I have five columns `book_title, author, Cover_url, genres, and descriptions.` for the genres column, the data that I scraped has the following syntax

> روايات وقصص روايات اجتماعية | روايات وقصص روايات واقعية |

here is [an image of exactly how it looks in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5c9Z.jpg)

so I wanted to turn this into a list with each genre being in a separate cell. Genres are separated by a new line and by '|'. first, I used this line to remove the '|'

```
df = pd.read_csv("/data/abjjad.csv",converters={'genres': lambda x: x[1:-1].split('|')})
```

I was able to achieve this

```
['روايات وقصص\nروايات اجتماعية\n', '\nروايات وقصص\nروايات واقعية\n']
```

but the desired output is this `

```
 ['روايات وقصص' ,'روايات اجتماعية','روايات وقصص', 'روايات واقعية']
```

I've looked into many questions similar to mine but haven't found a solution that works for me.

- [removing newlines from messy strings in pandas dataframe cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227748/removing-newlines-from-messy-strings-in-pandas-dataframe-cells)
- [Remove '\n' in text in pandas python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254186/remove-n-in-text-in-pandas-python)
- [Removing /N character from a column in Python Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67607354/removing-n-character-from-a-column-in-python-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can try splitting on both "|" and "\n":

```
import re
converters={'genres': lambda x: re.split('\||\n', x[1:-1])}
```

Then remove empty strings if present:

```
df.genres = df.genres.apply(lambda x: [s for s in x if s])
```